# B+ trees insertion/search?

Tags: search, data-structures, insert, b-tree

I am looking for good material on how to insert and search in a B+ tree. I already googled, but the stuff I found were really poorly explained. Is there any other good source online? Any suggestions for data structure books that might be useful? Any video lectures of any university? UCBerkley and MIT did not have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try walking through the BTree slides found at the following page. I found them very helpful when learning the material.  The slides are from the January 25th lecture.

http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse332/12wi/calendar/lecturelist.html

Answer (score 0):

For B Tree - Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) or Algorithms (Sedgewick & Wayne)

For B+ Tree - We have introductions to B tree in the above books just stating the difference in approaches.  But for better insight, we might have to go for DBMS books instead like - Database Management Systems (Ramakrishnan Raghu, Gehrke Johannes) or Fundamentals of database systems (Navathe)

Most algorithms and complexities are similar for both but with slight differences. So, understanding one can aid understanding other.